# Passing class methods as parameters, together with arguments

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I am writing a program that deals with a lot of randomness, and I am in the process of implementing automated tests that measure individual run times of functions.

I have a class which defines several functions, and I am looking to write a function that will test one of these functions with given inputs X times and return total runtimes. Then I will call this function with random inputs for each function my class defines, and print the results. My class is written similar to below:

```
class myClass {
    constructor(a) { ... }
    fun1(a) { ... }
    fun2(a, b) { ... }
    static randomInstance { ... } // Returns a random instance of myClass
    // etc.
}
```

And my code to test this is as follows:

```
 function timeFunction(fun, params, it) { 
   let t0, t1; 
   let total = 0;  
   for (let i = 1; i <= it; i++) { 
     let rand = myClass.randomInstance(); 
     t0 = performance.now(); 
     rand.fun.apply(this, params); // I also tried fun(params)
     t1 = performance.now(); 
     total += t1-t0; 
   } 
   return total; 
 }
```

And lastly I separate the functions according to their arguments (many functions share same set of arguments), and time each:

```
function myClassTest(it=50) {
  // Divide functions into different arrays depending on parameters 
  aInputFunctions = ['fun1'];
  abInputFunctions = ['fun2'];
  

  let a = ...;
  let b = ...;
  for (const fun of aInputFunctions) {
    const time = timeFunction(fun, [a], it);
    print(it + ' iterations of ' + fun + ' took ' + time + ' milliseconds.');
    print('\t Average duration of a single run: ' + time/it + '.\n');
  }
  for (const fun of abInputFunctions) {
    const time = timeFunction(fun, [a, b], it);
    print(it + ' iterations of ' + fun + ' took ' + time + ' milliseconds.');
    print('\t Average duration of a single run: ' + time/it + '.\n');
  }
}
```

However, this does not run correctly. When I run this (on Node) I get an error:

*rand.fun.apply(this, params);*
*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')*

How can I get this to work? What am I missing here about passing functions as arguments? I found a lot of guides about passing functions, but not much about passing class functions, because who does OOP in JS, right?

And there just must be a better way to do random unit tests, but I have a (relatively) simple use case and I'm no JS expert (clearly).

Comment: rand[fun].apply(this,params) Because aInputFunctions is storing the name of the function as a string, not the function itself.

Comment: That seems to have mostly worked, thanks! What should I pass as _params_ when the function in question does not take arguments? I had assumed passing an empty array would do the trick but it does not.

Comment: You can also just do  rand[fun].apply(rand)  
you don't have to pass a second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `fun` is a string, not a function, you can't use `fun()`. Also you can't use `rand.fun()`, as that'll call the method named "fun" and not use the `fun` variable.

What you want is either

```
rand[fun].apply(rand, params);
```

or

```
rand[fun](...params);
```

Comment: This answers my question, thanks! Passing an empty array as arguments doesn't seem to work when the function does not accept arguments, but the document suggests I should pass null instead. I will test this out as soon as possible.

Comment: @Levent An empty array should absolutely work

Comment: I have found the issue with the empty array. I have (mistakenly) implemented default values the Python style; I defined functions like _function fun1(a=1)..._. However, passing an empty array then initialized the argument a to null instead of the default value 1.

Comment: It shouldn't? That would only happen if the array contains `null`. It should use the default if the array contains the value `undefined` (ie. `[undefined]`) or was empty (`[]`)

Comment: Yeah, so I've read but it doesn't, oddly. Maybe I should open another question about this, but interestingly enough, I can call the functions directly without a problem but this method somehow alters the default parameters in a way that results in a run time error.

Comment: I found my mistake! I was passing arguments with rand[fun](params) instead of rand[fun](...params), which passed an array instead of arguments. That's why it bypassed default arguments. Thanks for your time!